# Where does File Sharing store SMB passwords

Tags: password, smb

Because of High Sierra 10.13.1, I had to switch from AFP protocols to SMB.

I only got this working by storing passwords in System Preferences > File Sharing > Options > Windows File Sharing

(strange: for iMac to iMac file sharing??)

Now I wonder: where are those passwords stored on my disk?

The dialog already says that this is less secure .......

Answer (score 2):

If you enable Windows File Sharing for a user in System Preferences > File Sharing > Options > Windows File Sharing the method to encrypt and hash the password is modified in the local node of the **sharing** host's directory service.

The file affected is /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/$user.plist. $user is the name of the user account you enabled in Windows File Sharing. If you enable several users all respective plists are modified.

Technical background: in addition to the existing authentication authorities another one (SMB-NT) is added. SMB-NT is considered weak.

You can get the current authentication authorities of a user by entering:

```
dscl . -read /users/$user authentication_authority #replace $user with a valid short user name
```

Usually you have to enable this for older Windows clients (Windows XP etc) only!

Comment: "Usually you have to enable this for older Windows clients (Windows XP etc) only!" :: well, I don't have Windows, I had to do this for H.Sierra 10.13.1

Comment: @Sciuriware Just tested it from a vanilla 10.13.1 to a vanilla 10.13.1 and it's **not** required to enable WFS. Maybe you applied some hacks in an older macOS on one or both hosts to increase speed/reliability (which requires to enable WFS now to get File Sharing to work)?

Comment: I did not hack anything of the sort; I just got authentication failures until I marked my user account in the Options part of File Sharing on all machines. Your accusation is futile.

Comment: @Sciuriware Asking a *maybe* question is **no** accusation ;-). Some hacks were often necessary/useful (e.g. force smb1 instead of smb2 in Mavericks & smb2 instead of smb3 in El Capitan) to reliably connect to SMB shares or get better speed...

Comment: Well, I did not; a useful comment might be the answer to the question: why did it work after the step I described. I won't blame anyone if nobody knows.

Answer (score 0):

Your passwords are stored in your **keychain**.

To see what they are open Keychain Access (Applications > Utilities > KeyChain Access).  Then click on "Passwords" on the right.  For instance, I use a Synology Diskstation for both AFP and SMB access.  Looking it up in KeyChain Access, I can see the account credentials stored.

[image]

Comment: Interesting; I trust that is quite secure.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question! The question is about the server side and not the client side!